# UICollectionView will not display cells in custom popupview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView inside a popupview which is just a simple view in a xib file. In the same xibfile I have my UICollectionViewCell like this:

[image: SamplePopUpViewController.xib]

The View is connected to SampleViewController class and the UICollectionViewCell is connected to PekProfil class

The code I use for displaying the cells is

```
    [_collectionView registerClass:[PekProfil class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"vinnare"];
_collectionView.delegate = self;
_collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

and:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"vinnare";
    PekProfil * cellen = (PekProfil *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cellen.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
if (cellen==nil) {
    cellen = [[PekProfil alloc] init];

}
NSString * iden = [_winners objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:iden
                              parameters:nil
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
    NSLog(@"fetched friends:%@", result);
    cellen.pekProfilNamn.text = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * ideno = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=640&height=640", iden];
    NSLog(@"IDEN:%@", ideno);
    NSString *pictureUrl = ideno;
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl];
    NSLog(@"PICURL:%@", pictureUrl);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    //roundpic
    CALayer *imageLayer = cellen.profilePicView.layer;
    [imageLayer setCornerRadius:5];
    [imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
    [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cellen.profilePicView.layer setCornerRadius:cellen.profilePicView.frame.size.width/2];
    [cellen.profilePicView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    //END
    cellen.profilePicView.image = img;

}];

return cellen;
```

}

And I know that the facebookcode works since I use the same code in other places.

However running this only displays this:

[image]

Any ideas why the content is not displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom subclass of UiCollectionViewCell. If you want to layout your cell in IB check include XIB file. It's not possible to combine classes like this in objective C. Register you nib your reuse identifier and make your image view and label public properties that you can then set in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly, just changed everything and made a new class with xibfile and registered Nib instead of Class.